# Benefit of method hiding in java

Tags: java, overriding, method-hiding

I have read about method hiding concept in Java but I am not sure I understand the advantages. In which cases would method hiding be useful?

Comment: You can hide class-internals from the average user.

Comment: @LukasKnuth I don't think this is the meaning the OP refers to.

Comment: Yep. I made the same mistake that @LukasKnuth and have to delete my answer... dumb me.

Comment: @pratikabu That's not called `overriding`. `hiding` and `overriding` are mutually exclusive concepts.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik thanks for correcting me.. here is the new one.. `Method hiding` is achieved when you define a static method in a `SubClass` with same signature as of your `BaseClass`. I've never seen its usage..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can read more here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html

In short, the benefit is that you can implement a static method in a subclass which has the same signature as a static method in a superclass.  If you could not do this, you couldn't add such methods to sub classes, and if you added such a method to a superclass all its subclasses would fail to compile.

BTW: You can make a static method not allow hiding by making it final.

```
class Superclass {
    public static final void method() { }
}

class Subclass extends Superclass {
    public static void method() { } // doesn't compile
}
```

to allow a method to be hidden you can make it non-final

```
class Superclass {
    public static void method() { }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your means:"f you could not do this, you couldn't add such methods to sub classes, and if you added such a method to a superclass all its subclasses would fail to compile"

Comment: If you could not hide a method in a super class, you wouldn't be able to define a different implementation in a sub class. i.e. it wouldn't compile.

Comment: Oh, I understand but i don't understand benefits of it yet. `Method Overriding` is useful for change behavior of a method on a instance but in static methods don't exist any interesting things such as it.

Comment: Perhaps the example added will help.

Answer (score 3):

There is no "benefit" to this, it is simply how the language specification decided to deal with situations when static methods of related classes happen to have the same signature. The language designers found no sensible way to provide an "override" functionality<sup>1</sup>, so they took the easy way out.

---

<sup>1</sup> There is a way to make overrides of static methods work on an abstract OO level, as evidenced by the way it is done in Objective-C. However, the alternative is harder to understand.

Comment: Overriding would make sense only if the class was also a kind of object, so dispatch on its type would make sense. For Java that would mean a radical change to its foundations. I don't see what way would there be to "deal" with it while keeping the foundations as they are.

Comment: Concur, In fact I would think it would be generally discouraged since the behavior is non-intuitive. It is too easy for a developer to think they are overriding a method when it is just hidden and thereby unexpectedly get the behavior from the base class instead of the class doing the hiding.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik But instances of `java.lang.Class<T>` are objects, so dispatching on them is possible, at least in principle. I can easily envision a change to the spec that replaces hiding of static methods with overriding, especially since the designers took good care to preserve full signature compatibility. The change to the spec would not be all that deep either. A change to the compiler could be quite significant, though.

Comment: I think the depth of this change would be quite great indeed. Dispatching on a `Class` object has little to do with the static methods of the class it represents and there is no easy path from the current semantics to the new ones. The type and its `Class` object are two distinct concepts. The closest I can see is something like Scala did, and you can see how much different that is.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik The dispatch on the class could be implemented by adding a vtable describing static methods, hauling around the class object in calls of statics, in the same way the `this` reference is passed around in calls of instance methods. Objective-C implemented it that way (well, more or less; their dispatch mechanism is done differently) and it worked fine for them. The feature is quite useful for building static factories - it lets you skip a separate class hierarchy for the factory objects.

Comment: But doesn't the concept of dispatch require variables to contain values being dispatched on? This part is missing from Java: we only have class *literals*, basically compile-time constants.